# Modular Inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Calculate the Following

$ (2^{19808}+6)^{-1} +1$ Mod (11)

I'm completely lost here for several reasons. First of all the large power of 2 just throws me off and secondly I've seen inverse equations before never an inverse + a number.

Could someone explain what's going on please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute $$x \equiv (2^{19808}+6)^{-1} \pmod {11}$$
we have to solve
$$(2^{19808}+6)x\equiv 1 \pmod {11}$$ 
By [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) we have
$$2^{19808} \pmod {11} \equiv 2^{19808 \bmod \varphi(11)}  \pmod {11} \equiv 2^{19808 \bmod 10} \pmod {11}$$
$$ \equiv 2^8 \pmod {11} \equiv 256 \pmod {11} \equiv 3 \pmod {11}$$
and therfore 
$$(3+6)x\equiv 9x \equiv1 \pmod {11}$$ 
Thus $x\equiv 5 \pmod {11}$
and finally
$$ (2^{19808}+6)^{-1} +1 \equiv 5 + 1 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, perhaps a little shorter and/or easier to follow: since 
$$19808=8\begin{cases}\pmod{10}\\\pmod{11}\end{cases} \;\text{and}\;\;2^{10}=1\pmod{11}\,,\;\text{ (Fermat's Little Theorem),  we get that }$$

(in the following all is done modulo $\;11\;$) :

$${}$$

$$2^{19808}=2^8=2^5\cdot 2^3=-2^3=-8=3$$

so

$$2^{19808}+6=3+6=9\;,\;\;\text{and since}\;\;9\cdot 5=1$$

we have that

$$\left(2^{19808}+6\right)^{-1}+1=9^{-1}+1=5+1=6$$